# Create method on instance IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio shortcut

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, shortcut

What is the shortcut in Android Studio for "Create a method on instance"? For example, say I have an instance of `MyClass` but not yet have `myMethod`:

```
instance.myMethod();
```

In Eclipse I can auto-generate `myMethod`. How can someone do this in Android Studio? I have a Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select function name and give below command:

**For Windows:**

`alt` + `enter`

**For MacOs:**

`command` + `enter`

you will have option to create.

[image]

Comment: option + enter for Mac

Answer (score 3):

**Quick answer**: move the cursor to the method and press `ALT`+`Enter`.

Android studio is based on IntelliJ and it's a very powerful IDE. There's lots of neat tricks that will speed up your development. For example, you could type out the code you want in your instance and then press `CMD`+`ALT`+m to extract a method.

I would strongly suggest you check out this video to show you how powerful IntelliJ (Android Studio) is for keyboard shortcuts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2GC6P5hPeA

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS: `option` + `return (Enter)`

Answer (score 0):

or for MacOS users `Command + Option + M`